# JSON post request to slack returns invalid_auth

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to open a dialog in slack through a google app script after the user presses a button but i'm getting the following error message:

```
{"ok":false,"error":"invalid_auth","warning":"missing_charset","response_metadata":{"warnings":["missing_charset"]}}
```

This is my code:

```
function openDialog (range, triggerId, token) {
    var url = 'https://slack.com/api/dialog.open';
    var dialog = {
        trigger_id: triggerId,
        title: 'Submit a helpdesk ticket',
        callback_id: 'submit-ticket',
        submit_label: 'Submit',
        elements: [
            {
                label: 'Title',
                type: 'text',
                name: 'title',
                value: 'teste',
                hint: '30 second summary of the problem',
            },
            {
                label: 'Description',
                type: 'textarea',
                name: 'description',
                optional: true,
            },
            {
                label: 'Urgency',
                type: 'select',
                name: 'urgency',
                options: [
                    { label: 'Low', value: 'Low' },
                    { label: 'Medium', value: 'Medium' },
                    { label: 'High', value: 'High' },
                ],
            },
        ],
    };

    var options = {
        'method' : 'post',                  
        'contentType': 'application/json', 
        'headers': {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token,
        },
        'payload' : JSON.stringify(dialog),
    };

    var urlFetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var message = ContentService.createTextOutput(urlFetch).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

    return message; 
}
```

Can anyone spot what I'm missing?

Thanks

---

Here's the doPost() function triggering the openDialog() function it reads a payload from a button in slack with `callback_id = "gasolina"` and `value = "update"` :

```
if (payload.callback_id == "gasolina") {
  var selectedOption = actions.value;
  var operation = payload.callback_id;
  var triggerId = payload.trigger_id;
  var token = payload.token;
  var inputRow = actions.name;
  if (selectedOption == 'update') {
    var keyword = 'no+money';
    var gastoExtra = '';
    var operation = payload.callback_id;
    var gastoExtraRange = actions.name;
    return openDialog (gasRange, triggerId, token);
```

Comment: Based on the error response I'd say something is wrong with the token you passed in the authorization header. Maybe its malformed.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea if there's a problem in the code that's not sending the token? I tested the imported values for the token and trigger_id and they are coming correctly. It seems it is not being "posted".

Answer (score 0):

I think that although your script is almost correct, a little modification is required. How about this modification for your script? From your question, I'm not sure about your current settings for using dialog.open of Slack. So this modified script supposes that the settings is correct.

#### Modification points :

- Reason of `missing_charset` is due to using `JSON.stringify()` to the payload.
- From [the document of dialog.open](https://api.slack.com/methods/dialog.open), the payload is `token`, `dialog` and `trigger_id`.
- `token` doesn't use for the header.
- `application/json` doesn't use for `contentType`.

When these points are reflected to your script, the modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
function openDialog (range, triggerId, token) {
  var url = 'https://slack.com/api/dialog.open';
  var dialog = {
    title: 'Submit a helpdesk ticket',
    callback_id: 'submit-ticket',
    submit_label: 'Submit',
    elements: [
      {
        label: 'Title',
        type: 'text',
        name: 'title',
        value: 'teste',
        hint: '30 second summary of the problem',
      },
      {
        label: 'Description',
        type: 'textarea',
        name: 'description',
        optional: true,
      },
      {
        label: 'Urgency',
        type: 'select',
        name: 'urgency',
        options: [
          { label: 'Low', value: 'Low' },
          { label: 'Medium', value: 'Medium' },
          { label: 'High', value: 'High' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
  var options = {
    method: 'post',
    payload: {
      token: token,
      dialog: JSON.stringify(dialog),
      "trigger_id": triggerId,
    },
  };
  var urlFetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var message = ContentService.createTextOutput(urlFetch).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  return message; 
}
```

#### Note :

- In my environment, I'm using dialog.open with the request like above script. But if this didn't work, please check the error messages and modify your settings.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
However, i keep receiving an error.

This time, it reads:
 `{"ok":false,"error":"invalid_auth"}`

Comment: @Mário Guidoux I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. It was found that your error was changed. From the document of [dialog.open](https://api.slack.com/methods/dialog.open), ``invalid_auth`` means that ``Some aspect of authentication cannot be validated. Either the provided token is invalid or the request originates from an IP address disallowed from making the request.``. Could you please confirm about it again.

Comment: @Mário Guidoux Also I have already confirmed that this modified script works fine under the correct settings. But as I said, I'm not sure about your settings for using dialog.open from your question. Can I ask you about the detail information for your settings? If you can do, please add the detail flow you did by updating your question. By this, I can think of the solution of your error. I would like to solve your issue.

Comment: thank you for your continued support! Find below the doPost() function that triggers openDialog():

 if (payload.callback_id == "gasolina") {
    var selectedOption = actions.value;
    var operation = payload.callback_id;
    var triggerId = payload.trigger_id;
    var token = payload.token;
    var timeStampRange = actions.name;
    if (selectedOption == 'update') {
      var keyword = 'no+money';
      var gastoExtra = '';
      var operation = payload.callback_id;
      var gastoExtraRange = actions.name;
      return openDialog (gasRange, triggerId, token); 
    }

Comment: @Mário Guidoux Thank you for replying. I'm really sorry for my poor English skill. Could you please add it to your question as update? Because it is difficult to understand the script in the comment from users including me. And the error is due to the access token. Also could you please add the detail flow for using dialog.open you did by updating your question? By this, I can think of the solution of your error. I would like to solve your issue.

Comment: sorry about that! I'm new to Stack Overflow. I added the  code into my question.

Thank you VERY much for your attention.

Comment: @Mário Guidoux No problem. Thank you for adding it. Your current error is ``invalid_auth``. About this, can you confirm your token again? If the token is correct, could you please add the detail installation flow for using dialog.open you did by updating your question? I'm really sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I confirmed the token by inputing it as a string directly into the code and the `invalid_auth` error persisted. Do you have any idea what else might be causing this issue? Perhaps something with the apps permissions?

Comment: @Mário Guidoux ``invalid_auth`` means the issue is for the authorization when the API is used. So in order to know the origin of issue, could you please add the detail installation flow for using dialog.open of Slack you did by updating your question? Because I have no information about your settings. By knowing it, I would like to think of about the issue.

Comment: @Mário Guidoux In order to reproduce your situation, I tested it at my account. But unfortunately, it cannot be reproduced yet. Can you provide the information about your situation?

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain what information you need? O couldn't understand.

Comment: @Mário Guidoux Thank you for replying. From the error message, can you provide the flow retrieved the access token? I thought that the access token might be able to be used for the open of dialog. When you had added the app for Slack at https://api.slack.com/apps , how have you set up the application and retrieved the access token?

Comment: I create a copy of the spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/196po69sd03dS2ihpgxVSrzeXYiGb3H3sY--GnaqIxSs/edit?usp=sharing) so you can check these flows easily. I also included a screenshot of slack's permissions in the file. Thanks

Comment: @Mário Guidoux Thank you. But I'm sorry. I can see only an image of Building Apps for Slack. Where can I see the flow?

Comment: If you click File/Make a Copy, it will make a copy on your local Google Drive. Than you open this file and go to "Tools/Script Editor".
Let me know if you have any problems

Comment: @Mário Guidoux I did it. Although I opened the script editor, I couldn't find the flow that you retrieved the access token. Where can I see it? ``invalid_auth`` means the issue is for the authorization when the API is used. So I thought that the flow when you retrieved the access token is required to be known. I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: @MárioGuidoux I am having the invalid_auth issue. Were you able to fix it? There doesnt seem to be any helpful documentation on this :(

Comment: @Mans I found another question that solved the problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51093107/9718818

Answer (score 0):

if you request by `application/json`.
You use to `header.authorization`.

https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/issues/302#issuecomment-825321015

#### API

- https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage
- https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage

#### Authorization in Headers

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
```

```json
{
    "text": "hello",
    "as_user": true,
    "channel": "U##########"
}
```