# can't open Slack dialog through google apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, slack-api, slack-commands

I'm trying to use google apps scripts and slack to automate my work. And I wish to enter some text with the Slack dialog to modify my google spreadsheet with google apps scripts. However, with the below code, I can't open a Dialog via `Slack-API's Slash command`. Is my code have some problems?

```
function doPost(e){
var params = e.parameter;
var token = params.token;
var text = params.text;
var trigger_id = params.trigger_id;
var slackUrl = ["https://slack.com/api/dialog.open"];
if (token == "[token from slack]"){
    var dialog = {
  "token": "[OAuth Token]",
  "trigger_id":trigger_id,
  "dialog":{
  "callback_id": "ryde-46e2b0",
    "title": "Request a Ride",
      "submit_label": "Request",
        "elements": [
          {
            "type": "text",
            "label": "Pickup Location",
            "name": "loc_origin"
          },
          {
            "type": "text",
            "label": "Dropoff Location",
            "name": "loc_destination"
          }
        ]
}
};
var options = {
  'method' : 'POST',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'payload' : dialog}; 
UrlFetchApp.fetch(slackUrl, options);
}  
else{
 var res = {"text":"failed token verification!"} 
return          ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(res)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
 }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- Use a string to "url" of "UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)".
- Use `JSON.stringify()` for `dialog` of the object `dialog`.
- `'contentType': 'application/json',` is not required.

#### Modified script :

```
function doPost(e) {
  var params = e.parameter;
  var token = params.token;
  var text = params.text;
  var trigger_id = params.trigger_id;
  var slackUrl = "https://slack.com/api/dialog.open";
  if (token == "[token from slack]"){ // Please input this.
    var dialog = {
      "token": "[OAuth Token]", // Please input this.
      "trigger_id": trigger_id,
      "dialog": JSON.stringify({
        "callback_id": "ryde-46e2b0",
        "title": "Request a Ride",
        "submit_label": "Request",
        "elements": [
          {
            "type": "text",
            "label": "Pickup Location",
            "name": "loc_origin"
          },
          {
            "type": "text",
            "label": "Dropoff Location",
            "name": "loc_destination"
          }
        ]
      })
    }
    var options = {
      'method' : 'post',
      'payload' : dialog,
    }; 
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(slackUrl, options);
  }  
  else{
    var res = {"text":"failed token verification!"} 
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(res)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(); // Important
}
```

#### Note :

> [When there are no exceptions within the dialog submission, your app must respond with 200 OK with an empty body. This will complete the dialog.](https://api.slack.com/dialogs#response)

- When it uses dialog, it returns the empty body using `ContentService.createTextOutput()` for above, because the status code cannot be customized by Google Apps Script. When the empty body is not returned, the error occurs.
- This modified script supposes that your setting for using Slack dialog has already been done.
- **If you modified your script, please redeploy Web Apps as a new version. By this, the script of the latest version is reflected to Web Apps.**

#### References :

- [UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

In my environment, I confirmed that this modified script works. But if this didn't work, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have been able to open a dialog! @Tanaike Just wondering do you know any good reference for learning how to use Google apps script with slack?

Comment: @Leow Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved. I think that when it uses Slack using Google Apps Script, the class UrlFetchApp is basically used. So it is important to build the request body using JSON object. About this, you can learn from Javascript. Here, please be careful about [**Apps Script is based on JavaScript 1.6, plus a few features from 1.7 and 1.8.**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features)

Comment: @Leow And when you want to use Spreadsheet, I think that [this document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) is useful. About the sample scripts, I recommend to search at Stackoverflow. There are a lot of good samples here.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just know about the Google apps script within a few days ago. I think I need to study more about it.

Comment: @Leow I think that you have already had the high skills. I can understand this from your script, question and your reply. So I think that GAS will be yours soon. If you have any issues, when you post them as questions, many users will support you.